# In battle, how many soldiers would an indestructible fighter be worth?

Tags: warfare, medieval, tactics, low-fantasy

There is a magical set of armour that protects its wearer from all physical harm. The armour is absolutely indestructible; blades will break against it, battering rams would bounce off it, even extreme fire is rendered harmless. There are no cracks or weak joints on the armor. While wearing this armor, a fighter is practically unhurtable.

However, he is not undefeatable. The man himself is still very much human; he doesn't have any super strength or endurance to match the armour's durability. His enemies can't hurt him, but they could still wrestle him down and then tie him up.

If he ever is captured, then he could be simply drown underwater to kill him, and then his armor could be stripped away.

Even while wearing magical armor, if the fighter did charge a large host of soldiers alone, then they would likely still overwhelm with pure numbers.

The question is - how many numbers would it actually take to overwhelm him?

Obviously, the magical armor is incredibly useful, but there's only one suit of armor and how practical would it really be? In a one on one duel the man would be invincible, but what is the maximum number of opponents he could realistically fight singlehandedly?

The fighter himself is the most renowned soldier in the kingdom. He is wielding a normal sword, and engaging in direct battle. He is aware that he could be overwhelmed, so he'll be trying his best to take them down one by one (i.e he won't be running into the thick of them stupidly).

His opponents are a number of standard infantrymen - they equipped with pikes, spears, shields and  bows. They are all disciplined and have been trained at arms, but none of them are exceptional warriors.

How many normal men would it take to bring down this indestructible fighter, and what would be the best tactic to do so?

Comment: Net, pit, splatter him with mud so he can't see, catch him in his sleep, hold his girlfriend/boyfriend and threaten to kill them unless he surrenders, just wait untill he needs to relieve himself then pounce. This seems to be a very story-based question at present. Try taking the [tour] and reading-up in the [help] about how we work, then you can [edit] the question to make it work here.

Comment: He's not necessarily invincible even in a one-on-one duel. If his opponent is skilled in deflecting attacks with minimal effort (there are martial arts dedicated to this), it's possible for the armored warrior (AW) to lose from exhaustion, especially if the AW is in a position where not fighting is effectively a win for the non-AW defender.

Comment: Plus, most armour is *heavy*, he won't be moving as fast as his un-armoured opponents who can simply overpower him.Story based or opinion based as to which is best unless you supply more details.

Comment: I don't see the worldbuilding element in this question. This seems like a classic A-vs-B-in-a-sandpit question. A better question might be "What weapons should we bring to fight this invincible goon?" An even better question might be "How would I use my invincible goon in a campaign to best effect?" or "How would I defend against this invincible goon in a campaign?" or "How would campaigns be different with a couple invincible goons on each side?" (actually, that one's been asked...)

Answer (score 3):

Here are three different approaches to your question.

**Six people**

It sounds like you're interested in a direct attack that results in an individual with a sword being immobilized. The closest thing in modern life is a cell extraction in a prison or jail. The objective is to immobilize (not kill) and the team assumes that the subject has a sharp weapon, so it's a fair comparison. IRL cell extractions can be violent and [controversial](https://www.nytimes.com/2014/07/29/us/when-cell-door-opens-tough-tactics-and-risk.html). According to  the [Nevada Department of Corrections](http://doc.nv.gov/uploadedFiles/docnvgov/content/About/Human_Resources/CellExtractionHandout.pdf), a cell extraction requires six people:

1. Team leader. Does exactly what you'd expect from the boss. Does the least and gets paid the most.
2. Takedown. Charges toward the subject and uses a shield to knock him to the ground or to pin him against a wall.
3. Right arm. One person grabs the subject's right arm and immobilizes it.
4. Left arm. Grabs the subject's left arm and applies wrist restraints.
5. Right leg. Immobilizes the subject's right leg.
6. Left leg. Immobilizes the left leg and applies leg restraints.

If the attackers really want to make sure they're successful, consider using two people to hold down each limb and a hold few more soldiers in reserve to replace anyone killed in the skirmish.

**However many people it takes to build walls and dig holes**

If I were facing such an opponent, I'd put up physical barriers around my troop areas. Debris and walls could render large areas inaccessible to the warrior and a few well-placed holes around strategic locations could result in the warrior being put out of commission.

**One skilled practitioner of aikido**

The indestructible fighter is in heavy armor that slows his motions. Over time, he'll grow tired. One lightly armored expert (dan) in the martial art of aikido might be able to disarm the warrior and deflect his attacks until the warrior grows so tired that he could be immobilized with rope.

[image: Aikido]